# Reading files from SD card issue: no file is visible

Tags: android, readfile, android-sdcard

I have a problem with my app. I'm trying to read files from my SD card, but I cannot find any file. Files are added to main folder in my sdcard. I tried also create a new folder and read files from folder, but I have the same problem. Other files from SD card (not added by me for app purposes) are also not visible. I'm testing my app on real device Samsung Galaxy A3. Do you have any idea, where is a problem, or what I do wrong? Below is my code:

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".RecipeActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Activity class:

```
  File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "receip.txt");
    if(file.exists())   // check if file exist
    {
        //Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }
        //Set the text
       Log.d("File text:", text.toString() );
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("Romek file:", "File not found" );
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"File not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
```

I added also below methods to checked whether my SD card is writable and readable. All methods return true.

```
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        Log.d("Romek", "External Storage is writable");
        return true;
    }
    Log.d("Romek", "External Storage is not writable");
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        Log.d("Romek", "External Storage is readable");
        return true;
    }
    Log.d("Romek", "External Storage is not readable");
    return false;
}
```

I used runtime permission and I can read files, but I have another problem. How can I get a correct path to my files in external SDCARD. When I using a Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), then I recived a path to external card in my phone, not SDCARD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your phone has android 6.0 or newer version, you have to ask run time permissions. More info you can get from https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: You are right this was my problem. Thanks for you help.